# How to search new documentation format / use old documentation format?

Tags: documentation

Salesforce recently migrated all of the API docs to a new format. The new format has some pretty colors and fonts, but is much less usable. For example the new format gives very little space to the table of contents, and no longer has a search input or feedback.

Is there anyway to revert back to the old doc format? Failing that, is there a trick to searching an api reference besides doing a global search of all of developer.salesforce.com? Is there any place I can provide some constructive feedback to Salesforce on this?

[image]

Comment: Similar sentiment and tweets here [Working links for old 3-panel docs?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78069/working-links-for-old-3-panel-docs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs team has just [posted a blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2015/06/the-new-developer-docs-portal-experience.html) about the retirement of the old portal and is responding to the community's requests for improvements to the new.

They did add a search widget (which is in the screenshot in the docs blog article). Currently it only appears to work for single word searches. I suspect it will improve over time.

This problem has the attention of the most senior people in the docs and the developer.salesforce.com organizations and work is in progress to address the usability feedback we are getting.

Comment: Hi Peter, I agree to the others that the new format is a massive downgrade and mostly a step in the wrong direction. It causes me a huge wast of time as described here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79521/why-documentation-deep-links-are-broken?noredirect=1#comment104547_79521 - the old thing should be brought back until the new one gets mature. The new thing is really an obstacle and prevents us for being productive. I talked with many other developers - and the all agree. In fact I met no one who like the new UI - and all of them gave good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Let @DanielBallinger create an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dp2YAAS), have @JasonClark [promote it on the StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/78390/594), then wait, pray, and hope ... (mostly wait)

A lot of these issues have now been addressed with their July 9th update. Mainly

- deep links work now
- search the current api
- table of contents

  - can see a lot more of it (smaller font, less spacing between entries, prioritize space for table of contents relative to other features, i.e. pdf, language, etc.)
  - expands/scrolls to the section your on
- can find the feedback widget now
- code in docs uses fixed width font
  (full details in the [update blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2015/07/more-improvements-to-the-developer-docs-portal.html))