# Why documentation deep links are broken?

Tags: apex, visualforce, documentation

Since the Salesforce developer documentation was never the fastest UI ever made by man, I enjoyed the old FRAME layout which allowed me to create deep links to content I use frequently.

Now having stored hundreds of these links in my Firefox bookmarks, it helped me to save hours instead of slowmotion-clickwalking through to UI. They look like this:

- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_String_instance_methods.htm
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_List_instance_methods.htm
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_Map_instance_methods.htm

Now all these links just died and I get redirected onto a meaningless page. I figured out that the help-system was totally overhauled and the new links look more like:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_methods_system_list
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_methods_system_list
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_methods_system_map

The path changed too much to make a simple text-replace automatically for all my bookmarks, so I just want to know if anyone else might also be trapped by this change and if there is no other way than manually creating the new links?

It would have been very nice if the old links where either kept unchanged as they where to the old style and old content - or if there would have been an meaningful redirect to the new content coming close to what I'm expecting to see.

Also I think the handling and performance became even worse with the new style than before with the frame-style-documentation:

- The navigation is now a div with a max height and it's not high enough for big screens.
- If you use the new deep links, the navigation can't be hidden (since it's a frameless design).
- If you use the new deep links, the navigation doesn't match to the content you see, but shows all nodes collapsed
- The search rarely bring good results on top (e.g. search for "list" should bring up "List Class" topmost imho)
- distinction between static- and member-methods seems lost. All methods are now in one huge list.

So I would like to know:

- What is the best way to use the new help faster and more productive?
- Is there a better approach than my deep-link workaround (since the links will be fragile and might die again at the next overhaul)?

What I found usable was Google "salesforce apex list" ==> "List Class" topmost as expected, followed by meaningfull hits... But it's uncomfortable and I would bookmark the hit again to save the keystrokes...

Comment: Other frustrations with the new documentation [How to search new documentation format / use old documentation format?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78225/how-to-search-new-documentation-format-use-old-documentation-format) and [Working links for old 3-panel docs?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78069/working-links-for-old-3-panel-docs).

Comment: Thanks @KeithC - so we are not alone with this pain.

Comment: I sent a [tweet](https://twitter.com/CloudMech/status/611235603259101184) to Salesforce Support today bringing these issues to their attention and asking what they intended to do. The last response I received was "Thank you Cal, I will be calling attention to this issue and will update you as I can. ^RG" I think they were oblivious to how ungainly the new UI is for those of us who relied on it.

Comment: salesforce docs just did a big update today which addresses a lot of these issues, see https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2015/07/more-improvements-to-the-developer-docs-portal.html

Comment: @RalphCallaway nice try, but the crucial breakdown of links is still present. It creates a serious pain for us developers and again I would like to ask that these old links should be restored. Also it should be made sure for the future that such links won't break again. This is not nice.

Comment: @UweHeim you tried that? all of my deeplinks are working with a couple exceptions. just in case it's not clear, i don't work for salesforce, or have anything to do with these docs, just flagging that some, emphasis on some, of peoples concerns about the docs had been addressed. probably reading your comment wrong, but it kind of seemed like you thought i might be responsible for this in some way

Comment: I tried it right now. Doesn't work for me. My favorites are String, List, Map, SObject, Object, ... Each INSTANCE and STATIC methods - just like this http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_String_instance_methods.htm and http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_String_static_methods.htm - once upon a time this was what made my day - NOW I will be rerouted to a senseless PDF https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/dbcom_apex_language_reference.pdf?major=186 - the distinction INSTANCE vs. STATIC seems to be lost

Comment: @UweHeim, please tweet any links that are still broken for you to `@asksalesforce on Twitter`. If you don't have a Twitter Account, post all of them here and I'll ask them to take a look at your post. Like you, I still find them and although the UI is improving, it's not nearly as useable as it previously was. Many of the Technical Docs hav broken links.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that at this point, given the updates that Docs have done, any links that continue to be broken should be considered as bugs. Since docs have committed to fixing this, any bugs should be filed as such with support, or through the documentation portal, which has a feedback widget running on it now on every page.