# How to make usable deep-links into the Lightning Design System documentation?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, documentation, lightning-design-system

Do you know any way to quickly lookup the same documentation for LDS again and again. My habbit is to use deep-links and create collections of the content I need every day.

Unfortunately the LDS documentation does not set distinct `title`-tags per page, which results into deep links labeled all the same "Lightning Design System". Also if you have multiple tabs on different topics open, their caption is the same.

[image]

Is there any way to deal with that more efficiently on my end? Right now I manually rename each links.

If not, are there any plans to improve that?

Comment: Seems like this would maybe be more appropriate on the Meta Exchange?

Comment: here (not in Meta) are lots of questions about the documentation like this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79521/why-documentation-deep-links-are-broken?rq=1 - solving it via the title tag might also be only one solution of many. So it's a real question and I would be happy with a workaround or any idea on how you handle it quickly to find the same stuff again and again. So I think it belongs here.